# Сервер локально и на виртуальной машине ведет себя по-разному

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman, виртуальная-машина, response

Имеется сервер на node.js, на моём компьютере всё работает.
загрузил сервер на виртаульную машину(ВМ), запустил там его и пытаюсь через публичный IP ВМ(указанный в моём личном кабинете(ЛК)) и порт сделать хоть какой-то GET запрос к серверу через ***Postman*** `GET http://84.201.164.124:3000/`.
***Postman*** выдаёт ошибку:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 84.201.164.124:3000
```

никаких дополнительных ошибок не возникает. в том числе в бэке ничего не логируется. сервер работает как работал и не крашится:

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Сервер запущен на: http://localhost:3000
```

обычно(когда я тестирую что-то локально) в терминале логируется ошибки, так же у меня подключен мидлвер ***expressWinston***, который так же не записывает ничего в файл с ошибками. выглядит всё так словно к серверу не обращаются и вовсе.
буквально два часа назад сервер отвечал на краши(выводил ошибку в терминал), была проблема с подключением к БД ***MongoDB***, полазил по форумам, подсказали исправить в строчке
`mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mestodb');` localhost на ip и после этого исправления сервер перестал регистрировать ошибки.
всё указывает на то, что я, возможно, неправильно ввожу GET-запрос или делаю его на несуществующий ip, но, до этого(исправления) он как-то отвечал и я уверяю, всё перепроверял.
Понимаю, что в описанной проблеме мало деталей, однако я постарался выдать всё, что может навести более опытных программистов на мысль где кроется причина. Никаких других зацепок у меня нет(как сказал никакие ошибки не выводятся).

Comment: **Сервер запущен на: http://localhost:3000** в скрипте нужно прописать что-то вроде `0.0.0.0` в место `localhost`) ну или нужен прокси типа nginx который будет слушать внешку и проксировать на локалку

Comment: @Jour  **Сервер запущен на: localhost:3000** – это я так написал выводить в консоль, чтобы по клику сразу переходил на сервер. так он открывается просто на 3000-м порту любого ip.
nginx мне пока на этом этапе не нужен. я просто достучаться до сервера пока не могу. может быть я как-то неправильно выразился

Comment: где код? listen... надеюсь ясно стало)

Comment: @Jour честно говоря не совсем вам понял.
`app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Сервер запущен на: http://localhost:${PORT}");
});`  – речь про это?

Comment: да.. `app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {` или **84.201.164.124** получается что сервер доступен только на локалке) соответственно чтоб достучатся из вне - нужен прокси в виде nginx например, либо вариант из примера, 0.0.0.0 - любой ip

Comment: @Jour либо я вас не понял, либо предложенный вами вариант не работает. во-первых у меня PORT – это переменная. она имеет значение 3000 и берется из env. ну и плюс предложенный вами код в принципе выдает ошибку логики, если я правильно вас понял, опять-таки

Comment: попробуйте локально обратиться к сервису, `curl http://localhost:3000` или `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000`

Comment: @nörbörnën не совсем понял вас. вы про сервер или сервис, что предоставляет ВМ?

Comment: в ваших терминах: я предлагал зайти на виртуальную машину и ввести эти команды при запущенном сервере (например, запущенном в другом терминале)

Comment: @nörbörnën да, так сервер отвечает мне
`curl http://localhost:3000`

Comment: @sharkavli вы вообще меня не поняли) сожалею, но это все чем я могу вам помочь - `app.listen([port[, host[, backlog]]][, callback])` как и написал выше) **выглядит всё так словно к серверу не обращаются и вовсе**

Comment: в вашем личном кабинете есть настройки открытых портов? там есть 3000 порт? или альтернативный вопрос - запустите ваш сервер на 80 порту и сделайте запрос `GET http://84.201.164.124/` - что получится?

Comment: @nörbörnën какой еще личный кабинет) книга по компьютерным сетям - вот тема топчик